# Magento 2: Product Attributes Option unable to use &

Tags: product, attributes, magento-2.2.5

I am unable to use "&" in option of product attributes. Below is attached screenshot.

If we add & to **Default Store View**   or **Admin** it get auto removed on save, is there any fix it ?

[image: Screen shot images]

Comment: Check the error in var/log after save.

Comment: It is a bug in Magento 2, I have tested and validated. It is due to escaping of symbols in JS and PHP.
An Issue is being created on  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19370
Thanks.